# Recommended RAM for setting up SharePoint 2013 in Azure Cloud

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, azure

What is the minimum RAM required to deploy SharePoint 2013 VM on Azure Cloud Service?

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-deploy-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Will 3.5 GB RAM suffice?

Comment: @DipenShah that link is for 2010 not 2013. For 2013 there is no way 3.5 GB will suffice

Comment: And to answer the question: The same RAM requirements is valid for Azure as for on premise installations https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx#hwforwebserver

Comment: @SumanChatterjee http://www.sharepointchange.com/uploads/9/9/2/6/9926673/sharepoint_2013_on_windows_azure_infrastructure_v1.pdf  . Down load  PDF for whole the information regarding 2013 in azure ,

Comment: @SumanChatterjee i think 7 Gb is sufficient in azure machine. I m currently using sharepoint 2013 in azure with 7GB RAM.

Comment: @RobertLindgren Thanks , I have just shared wrong link .

Comment: I am assuming that you are having a seperated database and only plan to install Sharepoint 2013.What all services are you planning to run on the server ?

Comment: I am planning to have 3 Virtual Machines. 1 having domain controller, 2nd having SQL and 3rd having SharePoint 2013..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Blog.technet here the some of hardware specification for dev/test lab.

**Active Directory in a Windows Azure VM**  Size: Small (1 core, 1.75GB Memory)

**SQL Server 2012 in a Windows Azure VM** Size: Medium (2 cores, 3.5GB Memory)

**SharePoint Server 2013 in a Windows Azure VM**  Size: Large (4 cores, 7GB Memory)

Read more here: [Step-by-Step: Build a FREE SharePoint 2013 Dev/Test Lab in the Cloud with Windows Azure Infrastructure Services](http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2013/01/07/step-by-step-build-a-free-sharepoint-2013-lab-in-the-cloud-with-windows-azure-31-days-of-servers-in-the-cloud-part-7-of-31.aspx)